# Thread management when populating a cache in a .NET web app

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, caching

I have a .NET MVC web app for data reporting.  When the app first loads, it requests a lot of data from remote servers then caches it locally in web server memory.  Before the cache loads, there's no way to respond to incoming requests.  Every request that comes in while the cache is loading must wait for the thread loading the cache.

1. If I use a critical section (`lock`) on the caching code, all the requests will block.  That's a huge waste of resources and I could even exhaust my IIS worker thread pool.
2. If I use async requests, the web requests will all return before the cache is loaded.  I can't "callback" a web request which has already returned its contents to the client!

How can I manage the threads properly?  Maybe there a way to move all requests to a single thread which asynchronously waits for the cache to load and then move them back out to individual threads once the cache is loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I use a critical section (lock) on the caching code, all the requests will block.

That is true. You can use `SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync` to asynchronously wait. This behaves like a lock. You probably want a solution for the case that many requests queue up (like 1000s). You can use a second semaphore for that with a max count of 1000 and a wait timeout of zero. If the wait fails you know that >= 1000 requests are running and you can fail the request.

Big downside is that now all your requests have some async component to it. Maybe you can do this in some central place such as an async MVC action filter. Otherwise you will be forced to make all MVC actions async which is a headache.

Be sure to correctly configure all ASP.NET and IIS queues.

> If I use async requests

Not sure you understand what async means in the context of ASP.NET. Async request processing is an implementation detail of the server. The client can't detect it. The request is not prematurely completed. Async IO (and any other form of async blocking) does not cause the request to end prematurely.

Comment: By async requests, I mean if in my caching code I make the requests to the remote server asynchronously.

Comment: @just.another.programmer so? I understand that you mean that but I don't know what you want to tell me with that comment. Does this answer the question?

Comment: I think this answers the question, I'm just working on how to use the `SemaphorSlim` in my code now.

Comment: OK if you need help with some concrete problem just post another comment.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put the Loading of the cache in a new thread: If you want that no requests are served you should load the cache in app_start. If the application loaded reuqests are served again.

Comment: What happens if a request is received while the App_Start code is still running?

Comment: I thing you get a timeout

Comment: That's a problem.  I want to respond to all the requests once the cache loads, not time them out.

Comment: how long does it take to load the cache?

Comment: 10 - 30 seconds depending on remote server response.  That's enough time for about 100 requests to come in under normal use conditions in my app.

Comment: No chance for a load balanced second webservr?

Answer (score 0):

Does the app require restarting often? If not, you can have some type of a fetch routine that requests updated data from remote web servers, and swap out all relevant caches in one critical section.

In essence, fetch the data in the background and commit all at once (you can lock during the commit to avoid contention over proper values).

Comment: If I swap everything out in one critical section, the threads all block in between.  That's not good for IIS worker threads.